# Samsung s6 click detection problems

Tags: android

I am facing some problems using `GestureDetector` with Samsung S6. The `MotionEvent` flow is following:

```
MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=5230.164, y[0]=995.625, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=9448672, downTime=9448672, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, id[0]=0, x[0]=5230.164, y[0]=994.6875, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=1, eventTime=9448687, downTime=9448672, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, id[0]=0, x[0]=5223.505, y[0]=1001.4341, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=2, eventTime=9448731, downTime=9448672, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, id[0]=0, x[0]=5217.2773, y[0]=1009.2318, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=1, eventTime=9448748, downTime=9448672, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
MotionEvent { action=ACTION_MOVE, id[0]=0, x[0]=5214.025, y[0]=1014.31665, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=2, eventTime=9448764, downTime=9448672, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=5214.025, y[0]=1014.31665, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=9448785, downTime=9448672, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
```

If I press on my finger, it usually ends up not being a click, I have to be precise with my finger tip to get clicks.

It seems that move events are fired very easily on this particular device. Anyone know workaround or some adjustments which affects click detection?

Thanks.

Comment: what about other devices? in my experience it is normal behavior. I mean even if I keep finger and not move it shows me that I move it a little bit.

Comment: I think the more dpi the screen has, the more easily it handles it as movement, so I was thinking if there is some magic variable which value could be changed to get clicks more easier through.

Comment: I have never faced that, but I think no, because it is just already existing callbacks which just respond what action happened...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my case I ended up modifying `GestureDetector` private field `mTouchSlopSquare` to have a lot of higher value.

```
 try {
        Field field = GestureDetector.class.getDeclaredField("mTouchSlopSquare");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(mGestureDetector, myValue);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```